# Korean Sports: More commonly used Synonyms

Tags: vocabulary, translation, word-usage, word-choice

In researching commonly used sports terms.

1. What is more commonly used for "Boxing" in Korea?  권투 or 복싱?
   My teacher says  복싱 is used more these days. 권투 is more traditional.
2. How about Weightlifting? 역도 or 근력 운동 ?

I tried looking through numerous resources, and couldn't find the more common usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 권투 and 복싱 are both frequently used. But I can agree with your teacher's opinion enough. But you don't have to worry about the difference of usage, there are almost same. I think it is useless to compare the using frequency of two words.
2. Weightlifting corresponds to 역도, not 근력 운동. 역도 is a kind of 근력 운동, which means just 'exercise of muscle'. You should distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

권투 is boxing (the sport).

역도 is weightlifting as sport (e.g., in the Olympics).

근력 운동 isn't exactly weightlifting: it literally means "muscular power exercise," i.e., the kind of exercise that helps you build muscles.  It's usually contrasted with 유산소 운동 (aerobic exercise), such as jogging, which are thought to help more with your heart, lungs, and general stamina.

Comment: nm, sorry I misspelled , this boxing 복싱

Comment: do they use 복싱 or  권투 more?

Comment: Hmm... just searching on Google suggests 복싱 is more popular these days, but I'm not totally sure (not living in Korea right now). I'll defer to others.

Comment: I see '복싱' more frequently than '권투' these days. But '권투' is still used more in conversations, though.

Comment: whats the google trend link? @jick

Comment: I simply used Google News search. Right now, 권투 https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%EA%B6%8C%ED%88%AC&tbm=nws says "300 results", while 복싱 https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=%EB%B3%B5%EC%8B%B1&tbm=nws says 1210.